# call from method in class to @class.method using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a class, that will be eventually turned into a library. To do this, I am trying to do something like what discord.py made, and the idea comes from it.

The code that discord makes is:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print('discord bot is ready')
```

Where the '@bot' is just an object that I created before by doing

```
bot = discord()
```

And the '.event' is a preprogramed and ready to use method. 
on_ready() is a function that is called already.

I want to have a way to create this from my own class, and from there mannage the entire code using async functions.

How to do it in my own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a class whose public methods are [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/). For example, this class implements a scheduler that exposes scheduling through a decorator:

```
class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self._torun = []

    def every_second(self, fn):
        self._torun.append(fn)

    async def _main(self):
        while True:
            for fn in self._torun:
                asyncio.create_task(fn())
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self._main())
```

You'd use it like this:

```
sched = Scheduler()

@sched.every_second
async def hello():
    print('hello')

@sched.every_second
async def world():
    print('world')

sched.run()
```

The class mimics discord in that it has a `run` method that calls `asyncio.run` for you. I would prefer to expose an async `main` instead, so the user can call `asyncio.run(bot.main())` and have control over which event loop is used. But the example follows discord's convention, to make the API more familiar to users of `discord.py`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for :)